# Do Loop Complication

Tags: procedural-programming

```
j[r_] = Exp[-r];

\[CapitalDelta][r_, d_] = 
  u^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 d j[r];

Do[k[d] = FindRoot[\[CapitalDelta][r, d] == 0, {r, 2}];
 l[d] = FindRoot[\[CapitalDelta][r, a] == 0, {r, 0}];
 P = r /. Table[{k[d], l[d]}, {d, 0, 1, 0.1}];
 rvalue = P[[Position[SetPrecision[P, 6], {a_, a_}][[1]], 1]];
 dvalue = 
  SolveValues[\[CapitalDelta][rvalue, d] == 0, \[Alpha]];
 Dataa = Flatten[{u, d}];, {u, 0.1, 0.99}]
```

I wish to get `d` values by varying the `u` value, but this does provide any result. Kindly help.

Comment: Parameter `s` isn't known inside `FindRoot`!

Comment: How is `rvalue` defined? Some kind of meanvalue of `k[s],l[s]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I just updated the code. The problem is, I am getting the required values when I am not using the Do loop to make sure the codes are correct but it needs to change the `u` values every single time. So in a loop, it might give the required values within an interval of `u` values. So how can I do it?

Comment: `k[d], l[d]` are to get the two roots of `r`.

Comment: `FindRoot` is not compilable. So compiling the loop would not help.

Comment: @supragyanpriyadarshinee Ok, and knowing `k[d], l[d]` how do you calculate `rvalue` ?

Comment: @supragyanpriyadarshinee Perhaps it's usefull if you show the working code (without Do loop and fixed u)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  `k[d] = FindRoot[\[CapitalDelta][r, d] == 0, {r, 2}]
 l[d] = FindRoot[\[CapitalDelta][r, a] == 0, {r, 0}]` I define like this and tried to get the first position where the two roots are equal and then got the r value from `p` definition. By substititing the `rvalue` got the `d value.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect identical roots? If you plot examplary `Plot3D[ Table[ u^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 s Exp[-r] , {u, {.2}}], {r, 0, 
  2}, {s, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]]` you'll see  the distin
ct roots `k&l`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes. I need it.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you.

Comment: In my plot you see two distinct roots. No intersection detectable!

Comment: But how can I get the exact points?

Comment: If a *simple mistake*  is the reason for closing, why not return a *simple answer* ? User Qp and community would have a benefit I think.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I got the point QP asked for:

```
ui = Range[0.1, .9, .1];
col = RandomColor[Length[ui]];
pic = Table[ContourPlot[ 
Evaluate[ 0 ==  ui[[i]]^2 + r (r - 2) + r^2 s Exp[-r]  ], {r, -.1,2 }, {s, 0, 120} , PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 3, FrameLabel -> {r, s}, ContourStyle -> col[[i]], PlotLegends -> { "u=" <> ToString[ui[[i]]]}], {i, 1, Length[ui]}];
Show[pic]
```

[image]

QP asks how the maxima of the single contourlines might be evaluated!
Using the list of pictures the maxima follow to

```
maxi = Table[pi = pic[[i]] [[1, 1]][[1, 1]]; 
Join[{ui[[i]]}, MaximalBy[pi, Last]], {i, 1, Length[pic] }]
(*{{0.1, {0.0107452, 99.2071}}, {0.2, {0.0405303,24.9883}}, 
{0.3, {0.0935606, 11.0851}}, {0.4, {0.17332,6.19987}}, 
{0.5, {0.282343, 3.90943}}, {0.6, {0.426874,2.62019}},
{0.7, {0.590204, 1.77192}}, {0.8, {0.752754,1.1197}},
{0.9, {0.887397, 0.547024}}}*)
```

result

```
Show[Join[pic, {ListPlot[Most[maxi][[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image]

solution without ContourPlot:

```
maxii = Table[{u, {r, s} /. 
NMaximize[{s^2, delta[r, s, u] == 0,Derivative[1, 0, 0][delta][r, s,u] == 0}, {r, s}][[2]]}, {u,ui}]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much.